# how to parse content within an iframe of swt browser in java desktop app

Tags: java, swt

In my java desktop application, I have a form that is submitted, and the target for form's response is an iframe within that browser.

I am using SWT browser component.

I want to access content in that iframe, to see if the submission was successful or not.

Is this doable? How do I access data in the child iframe?

Regards,
Arvind.

Answer (score 0):

It definitely possible.

You have to create your own JavaScript code, which will return `true` or `false` (depending on form submit). Then you can use `Browser` widget `evaluate()` method (see [javadocs](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/browser/Browser.html#evaluate%28java.lang.String%29)) and as argument put name of your JavaScript method. As return value you'll get `Boolean` with the result of your JavaScript method.

Comment: hi.. ok so i can get boolean value that is linked to my javascript code... I want to get result of submission to a 3rd party site... I want to get the content of entire web page that is the result of form submission... is that possible? (Pls keep in mind that sites to which I am submitting are 3rd party sites)...

Comment: I don't thing that it will be cross-domain request, because, the javascript code will be in your browser and will have to ask for page element (element of current page) (something like [get iframe content](http://roneiv.wordpress.com/2008/01/18/get-the-content-of-an-iframe-in-javascript-crossbrowser-solution-for-both-ie-and-firefox/)), i don't meant ajax request (by your JS code)..

Comment: hi i was looking at the javadocs, and there I found "getText()-Returns a string with HTML that represents the content of the current page. But there is no way to specify a specific window or frame, from which I want to obtain text...Do you know of any such method?

Comment: I don't thing so, that's why I talk about the JS code, which is capable of obtaining content of iframe in your current page..

Comment: ok, what you are saying is that the javascript method (that will return true or false) should be in the main window? or should it be on the page which is shown as response to the form submission?

Comment: I'm not hundred percent sure what exactly do you now mean. Could you please edit your question and add the main pieces of your html code to it..?